# Content Type "Article" is not showing when trying to add, but it is showing in Structure-> Content Type. Please help me

Tags: nodes

I don't know how i lost Article content type when adding a content. It is not visible for me.

Please find the two screen shots attached.
[image: Article not showing up]
[image: Article in Content Type]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try re-enabling the content types in the navigation menu.

Go to administration->structure->menus->navigation and you should see your article content type disabled in the menu. Just re-enable them and it should all work fine

Comment: I just checked in navigation and it is in enable mode only. And there is a reset button after that. And im able to add content from there by clicking on "Article" which is redirecting to Add Content. But still that is not visible in "Add Content"

Comment: Hey.... Got it... From the Navigation menu. I just dragged it under "Add Content" link and now i'm able to see Article. Thank you very much